# Issue getting variable from link

Tags: php

I have this code which permits me to pass a variable to another page, but the problem is i cannot seem to get that variable using the link. We have tried before, this same method and has worked.. could you please check it?

Thanks..

The link:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM pianificazione";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
<a href="lista_attivita.php?&id=<?php echo $row['job_id'] ; ?>"><?php echo $row['job'] ?></a>
<?php echo '</br><br />'; }
?>
```

The page after the link:

```
include('menu.php');
$id=$_GET['job_id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM attivita WHERE job_id='$id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
<a href="lista_attivita.php?&id=<?php echo $row['att_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['attivita_da_promuovere'] ?>-<?php echo $row['attivita_tip_merc'] ?>-<?php echo $row['attivita_da_svolgere'] ?>-<?php echo $row['attivita_tip_personale'] ?></a>
```

Comment: You're open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

You're also open to SQL injections... Either parse it as an INT:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

... or use prepared statements with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (instead of the default mysql functions that you're using, which are no longer recommended).

Comment: Thank you :) it works, i'm accepting your answer in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing it as:

```
lista_attivita.php?&id=<?php echo $row['job_id'] ; ?>
```

And then looking for it as:

```
$id=$_GET['job_id'];
```

You should use:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the URL that you're passing to the "page after link" you're setting "?id=xxx" as the parameter however in your script, your looking for "job_id".

Change the parameter to ?job_id= in your first script.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1)  **FUNCTIONALITY**

```
$id=$_GET['job_id'];
```

should be

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

since your link passes the variable id, not job_id:

```
lista_attivita.php?&**id**=<?php echo $row['job_id']
```

2)  **SECURITY**

Never, NEVER insert user-input data directly into a SQL query.  You are asking for headaches or worse.   The $id on your receiving page should be validated and escaped prior to doing any lookup.  If you expect a number, do something like this on the receiving page:

```
if (!is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
// throw error
}
```

It's not a bad idea to query your DB for valid codes, put those in an array, then check that array to see if the passed value is found.  This prevents user entered data from reaching your DB.

Something like this:

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM my_table WHERE display=1 ORDER BY id ASC";
$res = mysqli_query($dbx,$q);
while (list($_id) = mysqli_fetch_array)
{
  $arr_valid_id[] = $_id;
}
```

Then,

```
if (in_array($_GET[id],$arr_valid_id[])
{
// do stuff
} else {
// throw error
}
```